# Load Balance Azure VM Classic and new Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machines, load-balancing, azure

Can you load balance the classic virtual machine and the new Azure virtual machines in the resource manager concept?

Answer (score 1):

Your Classic VMs and ARM VM's can't share the same VNET, they need v1 and v2 VNETs respectively. You could join the two VNETs togther using a VNET to VNET connection, but [this document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/) states:

> A cloud service or a load balancing endpoint CANNOT span across virtual networks, even if they are connected together.

This goes for the ARM load balancer as well as the cloud service end point.

So the only way you could do it would either to use a third part load balancer availible in Azure, like F5 or Kemp, or use traffic manager to load balance between VNETs.

Comment: You think I should convert the classic VM to the new VM so both VMs match?  Is that the fastest and easiest solution?

Comment: @exposure if you want to load balance between them then that is likely going to be the easiest way to do it. ARM is the way that everything is going in Azure, and it does provide lots more flexibility. There are scripts out there that can help with the migration.